# Grails 3.2.9 with Spring Security plugin 3.1.2 got "too many redirects" with default configuration

Tags: grails, spring-security

Created a new app, added compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.2' and did:

```
grails s2-quickstart com.cabolabs.security User Role RequestMap
```

Then grails run-app.

1. Trying to access the /dbconsole, redirects to /login/auth
2. /login/auth got "localhost redirected you too many times." ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Is this the expected behavior or a bug form the plugin?

The doc, on the install and configuration section, doesn't mention anything about this https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/#configuration

UPDATE

Found on the documentation, section 5.3 (https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/) the initial RequestMap that should be added.

```
for (String url in [
      '/', '/error', '/index', '/index.gsp', '/**/favicon.ico', '/shutdown',
      '/**/js/**', '/**/css/**', '/**/images/**',
      '/login', '/login.*', '/login/*',
      '/logout', '/logout.*', '/logout/*']) {
   new Requestmap(url: url, configAttribute: 'permitAll').save()
}
```

Used that in the Bootstrap.groovy, and still got the "too many redirects".

Also, can't view the /dbconsole to check the database because it's blocked by the plugin.

Comment: Have you made any changes to application.groovy or to the projects requested assets like JavaScript or css?

Comment: @mcroteau no changes, just installed the plugin like the documentation says, run the quickstart script, and run-app. Couldn't find any doc about required changes to the application.groovy file.

Comment: It seems as if the following line in the `application.groovy` is causing the error

`[pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution proposed on GitHub and I tested it to work is to call clearCachedRequestmaps after creating the request map instances.

```
  for (String url in [
      '/', '/error', '/index', '/index.gsp', '/**/favicon.ico', '/shutdown',
      '/**/js/**', '/**/css/**', '/**/images/**',
      '/login', '/login.*', '/login/*',
      '/logout', '/logout.*', '/logout/*']) {
   new RequestMap(url: url, configAttribute: 'permitAll').save()
}

   springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps()
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late but I just ran into the same issue. The way I fixed it was to add the following element to the chainMap:

```
[pattern: "/login/**", filters:"none"]
```

The reason why this worked is because spring was trying to get you to login before accessing the login page, which obviously wont work. The line above tells spring to allow traffic to the login endpoint without logging in first (since you can't).